# How to put winamp on the tray icon?

Tags: windows-xp, music, winamp

I want that my winamp goes to the tray icon on my Windows XP, next to the watch. How can I do that? Is there any plugin or option that I have to configured?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's supposed to be part of WinAMP configuration...
Options ==> Preferences ==> General Preferences ==> Show Winamp in: ==> System tray
And, you can select the icon too.

Answer (score 0):

Winamp 5 can be configured to show icons in the Windows system tray and/or taskbar. Some find this a convenient way to access Winamp, others find it a waste of screen-real estate. To toggle displaying these icons:

1. Right-click the Winamp 5 title bar.
2. Choose "Options" then "Preferences".
3. Click on "General Preferences" in the left pane.
4. Check or uncheck the "Taskbar" and "System Tray" icons as desired.
5. Click "Close" to close the dialog box.